# Let $P(n)$ be : the sum of the first odd natural numbers equal $n^2$. Express in summation notation and use induction.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

[image]

I presented the first odd $n$ natural integers as $2n+1=n^2$. In summation notation I just factored this into $(n-1)(n-1)$. I am unsure whether this is correct and also I don't know how to carry out induction for this.

Comment: Base case is easy. For the step , use that the sum upto $2n-1$ is $n^2$ and add $2n+1$ to get $(n+1)^2$

Comment: $2n+1$ is wrong. The $n$ th odd number is $2n-1$

Comment: It is asking for the first n natural number and natural number are all positive aren't they? so 2n-1 would give -1 if n was 0 thats why I didn't think I could use that

Comment: The first $n$ ODD natural numbers are mentioned. Hence, $0$ is ruled out anyway. Yes, natural numbers are never negative.

Comment: We begin with the first odd number , clearly $1$ , which is $2\cdot 1-1$ , not $2\cdot 1+1$. In the formula, $n=1$ must correspond with the first odd number.

Comment: okay let me try it now

Comment: Okay, I can do it now thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A start:

$$P(n):  \sum\limits_{i=1}^n (2 i - 1) = n^2$$